How do i accept a list of base64 images in django rest framework
So i am trying to accept multiple base64 images through an endpoint to create a post and this is the object dummie data i want to send.
{
    "user": "username of the user",
    "caption": "Reasons why my Husky got mad at me today.",
    "location": "location of the post",
    "tags": [],
    "hashtags": [{"name":"Husky"}, {"name":"Angry_husky"}],
    "images": [
        {
            "image_name": "image.png",
            "image_base64": "base64_string"
        },
{
            "image_name": "image2.png",
            "image_base64": "base64_string"
        }
    ]

}

Here are my models:
class Hashtag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)


class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    caption = models.TextField(_("Caption"), max_length=5000, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(_("Location"), blank=True, max_length=255)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(_("Is Deleted"), default=False)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(
        CustomUser, related_name="liked_posts", blank=True, verbose_name=_("Liked By")
    )
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(
        CustomUser,
        related_name="tagged_users",
        blank=True,
        verbose_name=_("Tagged Users"),
    )
    hashtags = models.ManyToManyField(
        Hashtag, related_name="posts", blank=True, verbose_name=_("Hashtags")
    )
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(_("Date Posted"), auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-date_posted"]


class Image(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(
        Post, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="images"
    )
    image_name = models.CharField()
    image = models.ImageField(_("Image"), upload_to="post_images/", null=True)


Here are my serializers:
class HashtagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Hashtag
        fields = ["name"]


class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = Base64ImageField()

    class Meta:
        model = Image
        fields = "__all__"


class PostCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.CharField()
    hashtags = HashtagSerializer(many=True)
    images = ImageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            "user",
            "caption",
            "location",
            "tags",
            "hashtags",
            "images",
        ]
        extra_kwargs = {
            "location": {"required": False},
            "hashtags": {"required": False},
            "tags": {"required": False},
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        username = validated_data.pop("user")
        hashtags_data = validated_data.pop("hashtags", [])
        images_data = validated_data.pop("images", [])
        tags_data = validated_data.pop("tags", [])

        user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=username)

        post = Post.objects.create(
            user=user,
            caption=validated_data.get("caption"),
            location=validated_data.get("location"),
        )

        for hashtag_data in hashtags_data:
            hashtag, created = Hashtag.objects.get_or_create(name=hashtag_data)
            if hashtag:
                post.hashtags.add(hashtag.id)
            else:
                post.hashtags.add(created)

        for tag_data in tags_data:
            tagged_user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=tag_data)
            post.tags.add(tagged_user.id)

        for image_data in images_data:
            image = Image.objects.create(post=post, image_name=image_data['image_name'])
            image.image.save(
                f"{image_data['image_name']}.jpg", ContentFile(base64.b64decode('image_bas64'))
            )

        post.save()
        return post


Here is my view:
class PostCreateView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostCreateSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)


The problem is i do not know how to go about this i have searched and none fitting my requirement. I want to first save the photos first to the default Django media management system when that is successfull then i will use and s3 bucket
Please i require assistance from more seasoned and experienced django developer.

for image_data in images_data:
    image_serializer = ImageSerializer(data=image_data)
    if image_serializer.is_valid():
       image_instance = image_serializer.save(post=post)
    else:
               
       raise serializers.ValidationError("Error saving images")

In the create method of PostCreateSerializer, you create the ImageSerializer for each image data provided in the request. If the serializer is valid, you save the image.
